# Are animations automatically removed from layers when switching viewcontrollers?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I've setup a simple CAKeyframeAnimation with infinite repeatcount and added it to a layer. All is fine except that the animation is removed when I switch to another tab (or very likely any other mechanism of changing the active view controller).

Is this documented anywhere, perhaps new in iOS 5, and is there another solution than starting the animation again in viewWillAppear? The timebase is irrelevant in this case, starting the animation from time 0 would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform any work with View while it is not on screen, because it's just waste of iPhone resources. Besides your application can get memory warning and view will be unloaded.
IMHO the best approach is to set up graphics in `-(void) viewWillAppear` and start animations in `-(void) viewDidAppear`.

P.S. In `-(void) viewDidLoad` parameters of frame of view are still not valid and if you try to use them, you can get something wrong.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: Just start your animation on `-viewWillAppear` and that will be fine.

Comment: Hi Roman, you are absolutely correct, but I already mentioned these points in my original question. I'm looking for an authoritive reference on the question I posed.